# Printer screen not accessible from system settings Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing

I'm trying to install a printer via a ppd file on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When opening the system settings, all the settings are accessible (Display, Sound, etc.) but clicking on Printers result with nothing.

Anyone had a similar problem? Some ideas how to fix this that doesn't include refreshing all my settings?

[image: System settings print screen]